# Send PDF file to spool get stuck printing

Tags: java, pdf, printing, spool

I did the following code to read a PDF file from disk and send it to a print spool.

```
   public boolean sendToSpool(File pdf, int copies) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(pdf);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);

            DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(copies));
            pras.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
            pras.add(new RequestingUserName("print-service", Locale.US));
            pras.add(new JobName("PRINT-SERVICE-" + pdf.getAbsolutePath(), Locale.US));

            printJob.print(doc, pras);
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This code works for the most of printers I have tested, but some doesn't.
doPDF 8 is an example. It get stucked as shown in the image below.

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/fowesqcoz/printing.png]

If I open this document with Abobe Reader or Foxit Reader and request to print, a pop up is showed to me to save the new file on disk.

When I send it to PDF Creator it get printed too.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

---

UPDATE

I got it using a third part library (PDF Box).

```
@Override
public void print(File pdf, PrintService printService) {
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(pdf);

        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setJobName(pdf.getName());
        printJob.setPrintService(printService);
        printJob.setPageable(new PDPageable(document, printJob));            

        printJob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException | IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (document != null ) {
            try {
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```